# Non-Default VLAN on Dell PowerConnect 6224 is Blocking All Traffic. Why?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, dell, vlan, dell-powerconnect

So, I have two *Dell PowerConnect 6224* switches (non-stacked). On both of the switches I've taken ports `8` and `9` and assigned them to `VLAN 2`. The other ends of those ports go to two Windows 2008 R2 Hyper-V host servers (*Dell PowerEdge R710*). Each server connects to the two switches via a teamed connection for redundancy and speed.

The servers have their IPs as `10.0.2.5` and `10.0.2.6` with a subnet mask of `255.255.255.0`.

The VLAN interfaces on both switches have the IPs of `10.0.2.13` and `10.0.2.14` with a subnet mask of `255.255.255.0` as well.

Subnet `10.0.2.0/24` is bound to the VLAN. The MAC addresses of the teamed connections as well as the VLAN interfaces (from the two switches) are also bound to the VLAN.

My problem is that the two servers are unable to ping each other, or the VLAN interface IPs. The switches are also unable to ping the VLAN interface IP of their companion switch and are also unable to ping the IPs of the servers.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could tell me what I'm missing. I'm starting to get really angry with these switches...

**UPDATE 1** *(for Jim G.)*

I removed the team from the ports and assigned them the following IPs: `10.0.2.25`, `10.0.2.26`, `10.0.2.35` and `10.0.2.36` with a subnet mask of `255.255.255.0`. I then bound the MACs of the individual ports to the VLAN.

The servers can now ping to each other fine, but are still unable to ping to the VLAN IPs. Also, the switches are still unable to ping the servers.

The switches are connected via a single cable on ports `23` and `24`. The ports are still on the default `VLAN 1`.

**UPDATE 2** *(for Jim G.)*

I made ports `23` and `24` as trunks and assigned them to `VLAN 2`. Nothing has changed since the first update. The servers can still ping each other, but not the VLAN IPs. The switches also still can't ping the servers.

Comment: To eliminate some sources of confusion, can you try setting it up without Teaming?  Just use one NIC on the R710 and see if you can connect to one port on the switch.  Also, how are the two switches connected?

Comment: I've updated my answer with the result of your suggestions and the answer to your question.

Comment: Well, to start, ports 23 and 24 need to be configured as trunked and tagged ports for VLAN 2.  Try that and see if you can ping the switches from each other.

Comment: I've updated again, #2.

Comment: Do the VLAN interfaces need to be configured for routing or something similar?  Do they have to labeled management VLANs to be pingable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I ended up contacting a network consultant. It took about 2 hours, but he figured it out, I just can't recall what it was that he did since it was over a month ago.

Comment: I bet 10 to 1 you were missing the "Ip routing" statement in the config. Without this they won't do diddly.

Comment: Sounds about right, I just remember that it was a section of the config page that I never touched because I didn't think it was relevant, lol.